# How to replace a span with its children and do a regex over the inner text in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have few tags like

```
<span attrib="5_5"> <font size="3">Text:Hello World </font> </span>
<span attrib="5_5"> <font size="1">Text_Hello New World </font> </span>
```

At the same time , some folks didn't want font ... so they didnt have it

```
<span attrib="5_5"> Text:Hello World  </span>
<span attrib="5_5"> Text_Hello New World </span>
```

I need to convert all these to

```
<font size="3">Test_Hello_World_5_5</font>
<font size="1">Text_Hello_New_World_5_5</font
```

How do I do this in BeautifulSoup ? I can do a regex and replace text but I lose the fonts. I need to retain the children and in the same loop relace the inner text with regex . Can anyone tell me how to do this ? Basically I want a each.replaceWithChildren and then change each.text ... in the SAME LOOP since I can't lose the context . 5_5 is a number that comes from the attribute of the parent span .

In pseudo code I want something like :

span is a beautiful soup collection of all the span tags.

```
for each in span:
   span.replaceWithChildren()
   each.text = something
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this:

```
for x in doc.findAll('span'):
    s = x["attrib"]
    t = x.find('font')
    t.string = t.text.strip() + '_' + s
    x.replaceWithChildren()
```

**update**:

```
    t = x.find('font')
    if not t:
        x.string += s
    else:
        t.string += s
    x.replaceWithChildren()
```

Comment: Thanks Roman , Sounds like what I want . However its possible there is no font element - just an innertext , so how do I handle that case in the same code ? Is .string text content of that particular element as opposes to text which recursively appends the text of the Children and gives the output ?

Comment: @Nishant could you clarify a bit? is there attribute font of the element span or what?

Comment: t = x.find('font') here you are assuming all x has font element inside . Its possible that sometimes these spans have inner text only without a font element like my second example in input in the question  . I need to do the same operation on that innertext . Something like x.string = x.text.strip() + '_' + s and then replaceWithChildren ...athough in this case replaeWithChildren is same as replace ...Did you get me ?

Comment: Oh and no font attributes are not something I care about . Just the span ones . Fonts are just stylizers it might be there or not .

Comment: @Nishant not sure I got you right, but see updated. Or you can give me an example

Comment: Very precise . I was not aware of the string property . And the ability to be so dynamic in BS . Its wonderful .